# php date is showing incorrect time

Tags: php, datetime

This is what I have:

```
    public function getTime() {
        // first line of PHP
        $defaultTimeZone = 'America/New_York';
        parent::p('date_default_timezone_get():'.date_default_timezone_get());
        if( date_default_timezone_get() != $defaultTimeZone ) { 
            date_default_timezone_set($defaultTimeZone); 
        }

        parent::p( 'System Date/Time: '.date("Y-m-d | h:i:sa") );
        parent::p( 'New York Date/Time: '.$this->_date("Y-m-d | h:i:sa", false, 'America/New_York') );
        parent::p( 'Belgrade Date/Time: '.$this->_date("Y-m-d | h:i:sa", false, 'Europe/Belgrade') );
        parent::p( 'Belgrade Date/Time: '.$this->_date("Y-m-d | h:i:sa", 514640700, 'Europe/Belgrade') );
    }

    private function _date($format="r", $timestamp=false, $timezone=false) {
        $userTimezone = new DateTimeZone(!empty($timezone) ? $timezone : 'America/New_York');
        $edtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
        $myDateTime = new DateTime(($timestamp!=false?date("r",(int)$timestamp):date("r")), $edtTimezone);
        $offset = $userTimezone->getOffset($myDateTime);

        return date($format, ($timestamp!=false?(int)$timestamp:$myDateTime->format('U')) + $offset);
    }
```

The parent::p() just prints to the error log for easy debugging and these are the values I'm getting:

```
[18-May-2015 20:56:48 America/New_York] date_default_timezone_get():America/New_York

[18-May-2015 20:56:48 America/New_York] System Date/Time: 2015-05-18 | 08:56:48pm

[18-May-2015 20:56:48 America/New_York] New York Date/Time: 2015-05-18 | 04:56:48pm

[18-May-2015 20:56:48 America/New_York] Belgrade Date/Time: 2015-05-18 | 10:56:48pm

[18-May-2015 20:56:48 America/New_York] Belgrade Date/Time: 1986-04-23 | 08:45:00am
```

The problem is the System Date/Time and the New York Date/Time should be the same but they are not. Why would this be different and how can I fix this?

Comment: why did you set GMT timezone to New York? ``$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');``

Comment: Why are you mixing `date()` and DateTime? Also, do not put ternary statements as parameters of functions. I'd slap my team members if they did that,

Comment: I'd like to be able to get different timezone times. It's a copy and paste from the php documentation site. :P

Comment: I got it from here (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), so you can tell him you're going to go slap him. ;)

Comment: **Moderator Note** I've cleaned up the comments here. Please keep the comments on-topic to the post. Should you feel the need to continue discussing voting, then take it to chat.

Comment: @bluefeet: Thank you, could you also undo the downvote he did so I can get an answer to the question? Or should I delete this question and repost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$userTimezone->getOffset()` returns the offset from GMT

http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php

---

I prefer this approach. Personally I think the code is more readable

```
   private function _date($format="r", $timestamp=false, $timezone=false) {
        // cache the current timezone
        $tz = date_default_timezone_get();

        if (!empty($timezone)) {
            // temporarily set desired timezone
            date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
        }

        // render date in desired timezone
        $date = date($format, $timestamp ? $timestamp : time());

        // restore cached timezone
        date_default_timezone_set($tz);

        return $date;
    }
```

output:

```
2015-05-18 10:28:48pm: date_default_timezone_get():America/New_York
2015-05-18 10:28:48pm: System Date/Time: 2015-05-18 | 10:28:48pm
2015-05-18 10:28:48pm: New York Date/Time: 2015-05-18 | 10:28:48pm
2015-05-18 10:28:48pm: Belgrade Date/Time: 2015-05-19 | 04:28:48am
2015-05-18 10:28:48pm: Belgrade Date/Time: 1986-04-23 | 01:45:00pm
```